# Integrate $\frac{\sin x^3}{x^3}$ as a power series

Tags: integration, power-series, taylor-expansion

Today, I tried to do this by taking the MacLaurin of Sin to 4 terms, putting in $x^3$ in place of $x$, multiplying the terms by $x^{-3}$, and integrating. I came out with a sum that had $x^{6n+1}$ as the numerator, and $(6n+1)(n+1)!$ as the denominator. I don't think it was right. How should I have gone about this and what should I have gotten?

Comment: Try to compute the Taylor serie of $sin(x)/x$ and change $x$ by $x^3$ !

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$
hence:
$$\sin(x^3)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{6n+3}}{(2n+1)!}$$
and:
$$\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^3}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{6n}}{(2n+1)!}$$
so:
$$ \int\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^3}\,dx = C+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{6n+1}}{(6n+1)\cdot(2n+1)!}.$$
Also notice that:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^3}\,dx =\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin z}{z^{5/3}}\,dz $$
and since $\mathcal{L}(\sin z)=\frac{1}{1+s^2}$ while $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(z^{-5/3})=\frac{s^{2/3}}{\Gamma(5/3)}$,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^3}\,dx = \frac{1}{3\cdot\Gamma(5/3)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{s^{2/3}}{1+s^2}\,ds = \color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$
by the Euler's beta function and the $\Gamma$ reflection formula.

Comment: curious; I've seen gamma on Wolfram, but don't know what it is. What is it? Will I see it in Calc III?